# Inserting a column with specific characters of another existing column using substr() and regexp() Not getting desired output

Tags: r

Below is my data in csv and I want to insert a column named "sband" with values 2300-c1 for 2300-c1(of serving-band column), 2300-c2 for 2300-c2-XNDB(of serving-band column), 850-c1 for 850-c1-Bisector(of serving-band column) and so on.

Input:-

sidentity   serving-band    samplecount       samplemorethan10
6278(alpha)     2300-c1           34077                              0
6278(beta)      2300-c1           14656                             50
6278(gamma)     2300-c1           25172                              0
6278(alpha)     2300-c2           13523                              0
6278(beta)      2300-c2            7187                              0
6278(gamma)     2300-c2           11107                              2
6278(epsillion) 2300-c1-XNDB      31181                              0
6278(epsillion) 2300-c2-XNDB      15165                              0
6278(alpha)     1800-c1           10196                              0
6278(beta)      1800-c1            6302                              0
6278(gamma)     1800-c1           11829                              4
6278(alpha)     850-c1            23250                              4
6278(beta)      850-c1            10033                              0
6278(gamma)     850-c1            53181                            467
6278(gamma)     850-c1-Bisector   19870                           2258

i have tried this "temp1<-temp1[,sband:=substr(`serving-band`,1,regexpr("\-",`serving-band`)[1]+2)]" but my output is not coming accurate specifically for 15th row.

Output:
      sidentity    serving-band samplecount samplemorethan10   sband
 1: 6278(alpha)         2300-c1       34077                0 2300-c1
 2:  6278(beta)         2300-c1       14656               50 2300-c1
 3: 6278(gamma)         2300-c1       25172                0 2300-c1
 4: 6278(alpha)         2300-c2       13523                0 2300-c2
 5:  6278(beta)         2300-c2        7187                0 2300-c2
 6: 6278(gamma)         2300-c2       11107                2 2300-c2
 7:  6278(beta)    2300-c1-XNDB       31181                0 2300-c1
 8:  6278(beta)    2300-c2-XNDB       15165                0 2300-c2
 9: 6278(alpha)         1800-c1       10196                0 1800-c1
10:  6278(beta)         1800-c1        6302                0 1800-c1
11: 6278(gamma)         1800-c1       11829                4 1800-c1
12: 6278(alpha)          850-c1       23250                4  850-c1
13:  6278(beta)          850-c1       10033                0  850-c1
14: 6278(gamma)          850-c1       53181              467  850-c1
15: 6278(gamma) 850-c1-Bisector       19870             2258 850-c1-

temp1<-temp1[,sband:=substr(`serving-band`,1,regexpr("\-",`serving-band`)[1]+2)]

temp1<-temp1[,sband:=substr(`serving-band`,1,(regexpr("c",`serving-band`)[[1]]+1))]

Expected Output:

```
  sidentity    serving-band samplecount samplemorethan10   sband
```

1: 6278(alpha)         2300-c1       34077                0 2300-c1
 2:  6278(beta)         2300-c1       14656               50 2300-c1
 3: 6278(gamma)         2300-c1       25172                0 2300-c1
 4: 6278(alpha)         2300-c2       13523                0 2300-c2
 5:  6278(beta)         2300-c2        7187                0 2300-c2
 6: 6278(gamma)         2300-c2       11107                2 2300-c2
 7:  6278(beta)    2300-c1-XNDB       31181                0 2300-c1
 8:  6278(beta)    2300-c2-XNDB       15165                0 2300-c1
 9: 6278(alpha)         1800-c1       10196                0 1800-c1
10:  6278(beta)         1800-c1        6302                0 1800-c1
11: 6278(gamma)         1800-c1       11829                4 1800-c1
12: 6278(alpha)          850-c1       23250                4  850-c1
13:  6278(beta)          850-c1       10033                0  850-c1
14: 6278(gamma)          850-c1       53181              467  850-c1
15: 6278(gamma) 850-c1-Bisector       19870             2258  850-c1

Actual results:

```
  sidentity    serving-band samplecount samplemorethan10   sband
```

1: 6278(alpha)         2300-c1       34077                0 2300-c1
 2:  6278(beta)         2300-c1       14656               50 2300-c1
 3: 6278(gamma)         2300-c1       25172                0 2300-c1
 4: 6278(alpha)         2300-c2       13523                0 2300-c2
 5:  6278(beta)         2300-c2        7187                0 2300-c2
 6: 6278(gamma)         2300-c2       11107                2 2300-c2
 7:  6278(beta)    2300-c1-XNDB       31181                0 2300-c1
 8:  6278(beta)    2300-c2-XNDB       15165                0 2300-c2
 9: 6278(alpha)         1800-c1       10196                0 1800-c1
10:  6278(beta)         1800-c1        6302                0 1800-c1
11: 6278(gamma)         1800-c1       11829                4 1800-c1
12: 6278(alpha)          850-c1       23250                4  850-c1
13:  6278(beta)          850-c1       10033                0  850-c1
14: 6278(gamma)          850-c1       53181              467  850-c1
15: 6278(gamma) 850-c1-Bisector       19870             2258 850-c1-

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mistake in the regexp. I'd use the following:

`temp1$sband <- gsub("^(.*?-.*?)-.*", "\\1", temp1$serving-band)`